# Is there a way to simply replace string elements containing escape characters

Tags: ruby, string, replace

From a file i import lines. In this line an (escaped) string is part of the line:

```
DP,0,"021",257
DP,1,"022",257
DP,2,"023",513
DP,3,"024",513
DP,4,"025",1025
DP,5,"026",1025
DP,6,"081",257
DP,7,"082",257
DP,8,"083",513
DP,9,"084",513
DP,10,"085",1025
DP,11,"086",1025
DP,12,"087",1025
DP,13,"091",257
DP,14,"092",513
DP,15,"093",1025
IS,0,"FIX",0
IS,1,"KARIN02",0
IS,2,"KARUIT02",0
IS,3,"KARIN02HOV",0
IS,4,"KARUIT02HOV",0
IS,5,"KARIN08",0
IS,6,"KARUIT08",0
IS,7,"KARIN08HOV",0
IS,8,"KARUIT08HOV",0
IS,9,"KARIN09",0
IS,10,"KARUIT09",0
IS,11,"KARIN09HOV",0
IS,12,"KARUIT09HOV",0
IS,13,"KARIN10",0
IS,14,"KARUIT10",0
IS,15,"KARIN10HOV",0
```

I get the following Objects (if DP) :

```
index - parts1 (int)
name  - parts2 (string)
ref   - parts3 (int)
```

I tried using REGEX to replace the excape-sequence from the lines but to no effect

```rb
@name_to_ID = {}
kruising = 2007
File.open(cfgFile).each{|line|
    parts = line.split(",")
    if parts[0]=="DP"
      index = parts[1].to_i
      hex = index.to_s(16).upcase.rjust(2, '0')
      cname = parts[2].to_s
      tname = cname.gsub('\\"','')
      p "cname= #{cname} (#{cname.length})"
      p "tname= #{tname} (#{tname.length})"
      p cname == tname
      @name_to_ID[tname] = kruising.to_s + "-" + hex.to_s
    end
  }

teststring = "021"
p @name_to_ID[teststring]
```

```
> "021" (5) 
> "021" (5)
> true
> nil
```

The problem came to light when calling from another string reference (length3)

hash[key] isnt equal as string "021" ( length 5) is not string 021 ( length 3)

any method that actually replaces the chars i need?

EDIT: I used

```
cname.each_char{|c|
  p c
}

> "\""
> "0" 
> "2"
> "1"
> "\""
```

EDIT: requested outcome update:

```
# Current output:
@name_to_ID["021"] = 2007-00 "021".length = 5
@name_to_ID["022"] = 2007-01 "022".length = 5
@name_to_ID["081"] = 2007-06 "081".length = 5
@name_to_ID["082"] = 2007-07 "082".length = 5
@name_to_ID["091"] = 2007-0D "091".length = 5
@name_to_ID["101"] = 2007-10 "101".length = 5
# -------------
# Expected output: 
@name_to_ID["021"] = 2007-00 "021".length = 3
@name_to_ID["022"] = 2007-01 "022".length = 3
@name_to_ID["081"] = 2007-06 "081".length = 3
@name_to_ID["082"] = 2007-07 "082".length = 3
@name_to_ID["091"] = 2007-0D "091".length = 3
@name_to_ID["101"] = 2007-10 "101".length = 3
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the values, just store them in an array or something? Can you post the expected result?

Comment: expected result is the value to be stored as key in a hash. 

hash[key] = value

later to be called as mapping reference calling a diff key.
```
Currently: hash[key1] = value (key.length = 5) 
expected: hash[key1] = value (key.length = 3)`
```

Comment: Can you edit the question with the expected result (the hash you need) for a few rows of the text file?

Comment: Read the file as `CSV`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you don't know the correct character in your string. It might not be the same character when printing it.

Try `parts[2].to_s.bytes` to check exactly what is the character code of that unexpected character. For example:

```
 > "͸asd".bytes
 => [205, 184, 97, 115, 100]
```

Alternatively, you can delete the first and the last characters, if you are sure that every part of the string has the same format:

```
cname = parts[2].to_s[1..-2]
```

Or you can remove all special characters in the string if you know that the string will not contain any special character

```
cname = parts[2].to_s.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
```

Comment: thanks. the .bytes helped to build a solution. 
Instead of \" i needed to replace " only. 
now it works